Application migration from Rhel7 to Rhel9
I am currently using SeedDMS 5.1.21 application on Rhel7, php 7.2.24 and postgresql,  I am able to run application and view documents. But as Rhel7 support is going to end so I am migrating the application to Rhel9, php 8.0.30  postgresql 15 and SeedDMS 5.1.21 but I am unable to view the document. In php-fpm/www-error.log I am getting below error

PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/pdfjs/web/printphp.php


PHP Warning: scandir(): Failed to open directory: No such file or directory in var/www/html/pdfjs/web/printphp.php

And on console getting the error below:

Error: Invalid XRef stream header
XRefParseException
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects

I tried to use curl instead of file_get_contents() and zip->open(). But still facing same issue.

1 -> Check the dependencies
sudo yum install php-gd php-mbstring php-xml php-zip
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm

if you are using windows then remove the " ; " before these below showed extension
extension=gd
extension=mbstring
extension=xml
extension=zip

2 -> Check your PHP configuration in the php.ini
Ensure that the directory is within the allowed paths
open_basedir = "/var/www/html/:/tmp/:/var/tmp/"

or you can use log to get the detailed information from it
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log


I have checked the dependences, all are present except php-zip. Also extensions are available but still facing same issue.

do you have any error_logs. If yes, please share it and check whether the file is in the allowed path. I can say that you have issues related to permission and not on the code side.

I have checked the permissions all are 775. Below is error from error log. PHP Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /opt/seeddms/data/1048579/6598511/1.zip in seeddms-5.1.21/views/bootstrap/class.ViewDocument.php on line 690
PHP Warning: Undefined property: SeedDMS_Core_User::$_document_rights in seeddms-5.1.21/views/bootstrap/class.ViewDocument.php on line 1098
PHP Warning: Undefined property: SeedDMS_Core_User::$_document_rights in seeddms-5.1.21/views/bootstrap/class.ViewDocument.php on line 1106

Check and set up the ownership of the directories:                                                 sudo chown -R : /var/www/html
sudo chown -R : /opt/seeddms/data and make sure you have the directories               sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/pdfjs/web
sudo chown -R : /var/www/html/pdfjs
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/pdfjs                                                                                                Check the pdf.js compatibility with PHP 8.0.30. You are facing the issues with the file permission only, check wether it exist or not.
